# Change Japanese(Anthy) Font in Gnome3

Tags: gnome, fonts, ibus, input-method, japanese

I'm trying to find a way to change the font used in Gnome3 when using the Japanese(Anthy) input method. I added Japanese(Anthy) as an Input Source under Settings -> Keyboard.

[image]

I ran `ibus-setup` and selected a custom font, but when I switch to Japanese (Anthy) it still used the default font.

[image]

- ibus version 1.5.25
- gnome 40.4.0
- ibus-anthy 1.5.13

Edit:

`fc-match -s | head -15` output

```
DejaVuSans.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Book"
DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Bold"
DejaVuSans-Oblique.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Oblique"
DejaVuSans-BoldOblique.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Bold Oblique"
NimbusSans-Regular.otf: "Nimbus Sans" "Regular"
odosung.ttc: "AR PL New Sung" "Reguler"
NotoSans-Regular.ttf: "Noto Sans" "Regular"
NotoSansAdlam-Regular.ttf: "Noto Sans Adlam" "Regular"
NotoSansHebrew-Regular.ttf: "Noto Sans Hebrew" "Regular"
NotoSansWarangCiti-Regular.ttf: "Noto Sans Warang Citi" "Regular"
DejaVuMathTeXGyre.ttf: "DejaVu Math TeX Gyre" "Regular"
DejaVuSansMono.ttf: "DejaVu Sans Mono" "Book"
DejaVuSerif.ttf: "DejaVu Serif" "Book"
NotoKufiArabic-Regular.ttf: "Noto Kufi Arabic" "Regular"
NotoSansHanifiRohingya-Regular.ttf: "Noto Sans Hanifi Rohingya" "Regular"
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and show us the output of this terminal command: `fc-match -s | head -15`

Comment: updated with output

Comment: Thanks. I don't see _Noto Sans CJK_ there, and you gave the explanation in a comment to my answer: You are on Arch, not Ubuntu. Hence your question is off topic here.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a distinct answer, but an attempt to provide some hints.

First: I don't think that `ibus-setup` is the right tool when using IBus on a GNOME desktop.

Second: I see that you tried to use *Source Hans Sans*, and that makes me a bit confused since *Noto Sans CJK* — which is basically the same font — is installed by default on Ubuntu.

Comment: Do you know what the ibus configuration tool is for GNOME?

Comment: One comment: This is GNOME running on top of Arch

Comment: Arch is off-topic here.